# Is there a way to use custom arguments for npm install when deploying in Clever Clouds?

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, clever-cloud

I'm working on a `NextJS` application which is deployed through Clever Clouds.

One of the newer dependency require the argument `--legacy-peer-deps` to be passed with npm install.

When deploying to Clever Cloud, the log only shows the command `npm install --no-progress`, and then fail because of this dependency.

I have tried putting the command in custom environment variable : CC_NODE_BUILD_TOOL or CC_CUSTOM_BUILD_TOOL but the deployment fail the same way.

I have tried putting it in the scripts.install, but this cause the install to recursively call itself each time it is finished.

Is there really no way to circumvent this ? Is there a way to pass the "strict-peer-deps" of npm to false ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `HOOK` to run this command after the automatic install step, you can find the list of available hooks here: https://www.clever-cloud.com/doc/develop/build-hooks/.

I advise you to use the `CC_POST_BUILD_HOOK` environment variable to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However i need to change the "automatic install step" not what happens after. It's this step that fails the deployment.

Comment: You can't add this options to the automatic install step, that's why I am telling you this. To sum up, you are only able to do this after with a hook.

Comment: So there is no solution since it will always fail. Thanks for letting me know. Guess I'll be dropping this library.